# why Python script if statement not working correctly?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

I was writing [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

```
w = [0 for x in xrange(item_count+1)]  
v = [0 for x in xrange(item_count+1)]
```

assigned value and weight (v, w) respectively. created

```
c = [[0 for x in xrange(capacity+1)] for x in xrange(item_count+1)]
```

c, w and v is assigned values after this respectively(not zero)

```
for i in range(1,item_count+1):  
    #for ever possible weight  
    for j in range(0,capacity+1):       
    #can we add this item to this?  
        if w[i] <= j :  
            c[i][j] = max(c[i-1][j], v[i] + c[i-1][j-w[i]])  
        else:  
            c[i][j] = c[i-1][j]
```

This if `w[i] <= j:` is always `False` even if on printing `w[i]` seems greater than `j`. Dont know why?

Comment: you never assign to w and it is initialized to 0. so is always zero

Comment: Hint: `w = [0 for x in xrange(item_count+1)]` could be written `w = [0] * (item_count + 1)`. Same for the others

Comment: Actually, shouldn't `w[i] <= j` be *`True`* every time?

Comment: actually i forgot to add that after initilizing i assigned value using input from stdin to v and w so its not 0

Answer (score 2):

w[i] is always 0 in your code. Never touched after initilization

Comment: actually i forgot to add that after initilizing i assigned value using input from stdin to v and w